# Fetch data from server and show on app kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I'm working on a simple grocery app .

I put my product in a recyclerview that comes from database room table and display them in my home activty(main screen ) .

I have a Json url that want to use it with retrofit to fetch data from the server .

ok , is the correct way fetch data from server with retrofit and store it in the room database and after that display them ?
or just fetch data with retrofit and without storing it display them?

I a little bit confused with this

can any one help me with this ?

thank's in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you! If you download the data and store it in room first this data will be available offline as well. But any changes you make on the server to the data or on your phone should the be synchronised to both room and the server.

Skipping room and just displaying data from your server in your recyclerView straight away requires less work but loses the possibility to view the items offline.

So consider the use-case of your app if it should be online only or if it should work online and offline (and then sync data when a connection is available again).

Comment: which one you recommend . it's not matter for me . i just want an efficient and good quality app .

Comment: @BahadorEslami I would probably start with online only. And then if the need arises add the offline part later.